# PhoneGap - Image height, with and resolution for iPhone 3 and 4

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am developing a small iPhone application using [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com), and I'm having trouble figuring out the dimensions of images, I'm using as full-screen backgrounds... Specifically the height, the width, and the resolution of images for the iPhone 3G and 3GS.. *and* the iPhone 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?: http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html